# Vue Quasar Framework with Cordova: cordova-plugin-firebasex gives error, "Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')" when attempting to build IOS

Tags: cordova, apple-push-notifications, cordova-plugins, quasar-framework

I am attempting to enable push notifications for ios on my app and I believe I have gone through the necessary instructions to implement it. Cordova-plugin-firebasex seems to be the recommended package used to integrate ios push notifications with my quasar/cordova project. When I attempt to build cordova-ios, I receive this error and it prevents me from building and testing out my code. It does not give me much else in terms of information on the error. Any insight would be truly helpful.

Here is the error I recieve. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/81pHU.png)

I tried uninstalling the package and ios platform and reinstalling. I attempting to reimport my GoogleService-info.plist file just in case it might be corrupt. I attempted to build without the firebasex plugin and use xcode to install the firebase packages, but the app would not install on the device.